# Windows PATH variable is different if whether running CMD as admin or not

Tags: windows, scala, cmd

I just installed scala but I can't call it from the command line. So I dutifully checked my path through the environmental variables of the control panel and saw the scala folder present. If I type `scala` from cmd within that folder, it works fine.

So I tried `echo %PATH%` from windows cmd to see any problem. If running a normal command window, I get almost the same path except it's missing the scala path item. If I run the command line (Admin), then the echoed path matches the environment variables version. Under this admin setting, `scala` works fine.

There is no user path variable defined, it's only a system variable.

I've never seen this before. Why is there a difference between admin path and non-admin path? And how do I access the scala path item from the non-admin command line?

Thanks!

Comment: because windows has two paths. one's system-wide, and the other's per-user. Probably the admin user has the scala stuff in its path, while your other account(s) don't.

Comment: you should set the PATH of scala in the system path. would work for everyone.

Comment: If you only want it for one user, place it into the user PATH. Windows will append the user PATH to the system PATH.

Comment: You probably just need to reboot.

Comment: I understand that the user Path vs system Path is visible in the environmental variables window. The top window is the user variable space, the bottom is the system space. If it shows up on the bottom window, then it should be a system path. Then, I assume, it should show up when echoing path at the command line, when in admin mode or not, right?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, it was caused by the environment variables not being refreshed.  A reboot would have solved it, however there is a way to refresh the environment variables without a reboot.

1. Open cmd prompt window
2. Input `set PATH=C`
3. close and restart cmd prompt window
4. input `echo %PATH%` to check

This worked for me in Windows 10.